# Why does a sum of a larger array take less time

Tags: rust

When `sum` is run on a vector with 100 elements it takes 9ns to complete, when run with 10 elements it takes 13ns.

Demonstrated with the following code

```
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;

use test::{black_box, Bencher};

#[bench]
fn bench_10(b: &mut Bencher){
    let set: Vec<u32> = (0..10u32).collect();
    b.iter(|| {
        let result: u32 = set.iter().sum();
        black_box(result) // So the compile doesn't optimise out function
    })
}

#[bench]
fn bench_100(b: &mut Bencher){
    let set: Vec<u32> = (0..100u32).collect();
    b.iter(|| {
        let result: u32 = set.iter().sum();
        black_box(result)
    })
}
```

Results in this output with `cargo bench`

```
test sum::tests::bench_iter_10     ... bench:       13 ns/iter (+/- 1)
test sum::tests::bench_iter_100    ... bench:        9 ns/iter (+/- 1)
```

Some more results:

```
Elements | Time
10       | 14ns
12       | 14ns
50       | 10ns
80       | 11ns
90       | 12ns
100      | 9ns
110      | 14ns
120      | 13ns
150      | 16ns
10,000   | 913ns
```

Is there any reason behind this, or is it just something to be expected with the nightly builds? Tested with `rustc 1.15.0-nightly (3bf2be9ce 2016-11-22)`

Comment: Did you run the benchmark more than once?

Comment: Yes many times, same every time. Also thanks for the edit Chris, complete brain fart.

Comment: What happens if you swap the order of the tests?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually creating a vector and summing it at runtime rather than computing it at compile time?

Comment: I've tried running the tests independently(comment one out and run then swap) and I still get 9ns and 13ns. I'm not certain whether it's computing at compile time or not. Does rust use a different method for a longer array?

Comment: It's a shame the playground doesn't do benchmarks (for the convenient disassembly/MIR options).

Comment: @timlyo: Have you tried with an absurdly large array (like... 100,000 elements to start with)? Because if the optimizer is good, it can compute at compile-time that your sum is 0 (which is why inspecting the generated LLVM IR/assembly would be great). For reference, 9ns is 36 CPU cycles on a 4GHz processor, a 100,000 elements array cannot be added in 36 instructions, so would give away whether the compiler optimizes the sum out or not. Also, try 12, it's a multiple of 4, so more vectorization friendly than 10 or 50.

Comment: @MatthieuM. added the results to the post, seems to be a definite sweet spot around 100

Comment: Your input is not black-boxed. The whole computation can be evaluated at compile time (will happen for short vecs).

Comment: Cannot reproduce with `rustc 1.15.0-nightly (ba872f270 2016-11-17)` — bench_10 -> 2 ns/iter (+/- 0);  bench_100 -> 5 ns/iter (+/- 0).

Comment: These arrays are so short that I'd expect the benchmark time to be completely overshadowed by variance in running the test, or by things like the memory allocation itself.